# How to get book title from ISBN with Knowledge Graph?

Tags: php, google-api, google-knowledge-graph

I volunteer in a communal library and I'm in charge of the digital transition.
I'm using the free and open-source software [PMB](http://www.sigb.net/index.php?lvl=cmspage&pageid=17) and I want to automate the retrieval of book titles with the Knowledge Graph API (which is not possible with PMB, or I missed something).
Why to use Knowledge Graph instead of ISBNdb or another free ISBN API ? Because none is as complete and qualitative as KG.

For example: I take the ISBN of a French book : *9782884613736* ("Le foot illustré de A à Z").
Not found on ISBNdb.com, etc.

So, on when I google it, the Knowledge Graph returns me exactly what I want :

[> Screenshot of what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5zN4.png)

But when i'm using the API :

`GET https://kgsearch.googleapis.com/v1/entities:search?languages=fr&query=9782884613736&types=Book&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

```
{
    "@context": {
        "@vocab": "http://schema.org/",
        "goog": "http://schema.googleapis.com/",
        "EntitySearchResult": "goog:EntitySearchResult",
        "detailedDescription": "goog:detailedDescription",
        "kg": "http://g.co/kg"
    },
    "@type": "ItemList",
    "itemListElement": [
    ]
}
```

Nothing returned to my GET request. (It works properly if I request the book title, it returns well the informations)
I tried with different types according to schema.org : *Book*,  *BookSeries*,  *BookFormatType*.

Is there a way to use KG API as I want ?
I'm totally open to all suggestions (even to use another method to reach my aim).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `ISBN` seems to be wrong or doesn't exits on google DB, here's a sample using google books api:

**ISBN_10** : `2884610154`

https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?languages=fr&q=isbn:2884610154

**ISBN_13** : `9782884610155`

https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?languages=fr&q=isbn:9782884610155

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The ISBN isn't wrong (I just scanned it from the barcode of the book), it is only missing on international databases, that's why I want to use KG with `FR` parameter.
But you're giving me links of Google Books API, which is really, really poor if you are looking for non-english books.

Comment: The isbn doesn't match https://www.amazon.fr/foot-illustr%C3%A9-%C3%A0-Z/dp/2840450755, but it also doesn't  exist on google books

Comment: Yes, i saw it this morning too, but I have to refer to the barcode of my book and not to an Amazon ISBN... And again, that's why I want to use KG and not Google API whose content is significantly different. Thank you for your time anyway

Comment: I think you're out of luck because the book is 20 years old and google doesn't know about it, which is rare...

Comment: I have the same problem with a new book (with real success in France) : 9782221157855. Google Books API returns false informations (wrong title), but KG returns true informations and KG API returns no informations (as in the first post). I think it's about a bad use of KG API but I don't know how to get away with the parameters or, quite simply, the API...